# Saving Nested Objects

Tags: grails, groovy

My `Record` domain class is as follows:

```
Record.groovy

Person person
Schedule schedule
String nameOfRecord
```

My RecordService.groovy is as follows:

```
def saveRecord (params) {
    def personInstance = Person.get(params.record.person.id)
    def scheduleInstance = Schedule.get(params.record.schedule.id)
    def nameOfTheRecord = params.nameOfRecord

    // At this point i want to save my Record. How can i do it
    def rec = new Record(params)

    rec.save(flush: true)

}
```

`Person` and `Schedule` are not getting saved in the `Record` table. How can i save these ?

I think the problem is with `def rec = new Record(params)` and i am not saving 
 `scheduleInstance` and `personInstance` in it. How to solve this ?

UPDATE

```
<g:form controller="record" action="save">
<g:hiddenField name="record.person.id" value="${record.person.id}" />
<g:hiddenField name="record.schedule.id" value="${record.schedule.id}" />

... And other input field
```

Answer (score 0):

> Person and Schedule are not getting saved in the Record table. How can i save these ?

I presume you mean *foreign keys* to Person and Schedule are not being saved in the Record? If so, the following should work

```
def saveRecord(Record record) {
    rec.save(flush: true)
}
```

If this seems like magic, you should read the [data binding docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding), in particular the section "Binding Request Data to the Model".

Comment: I am actually, getting values from the view class. I have updated my code. Therefore in that case i have to retrieve values `params` attribute. So in that case i am not able to use `def saveRecord(Record record) {}`

Comment: @Illep sorry, I don't understand your comment

Answer (score 0):

@Ilep I think what you are looking for is a hasOne relationship:
http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/hasOne.html
It will handle better not only relationships, it will also handle better deletes. You should also define the BelongsTo relation if applies.

You have a problem in your syntax too:

```
def personInstance = Person.get(params.record.person.id)
def scheduleInstance = Schedule.get(params.record.schedule.id)
def nameOfTheRecord = params.nameOfRecord

// At this point i want to save my Record. How can i do it
def rec = new Record(params)
```

Should be:

```
def personInstance = Person.get(params.record.person.id)
def scheduleInstance = Schedule.get(params.record.schedule.id)
def nameOfTheRecord = params.nameOfRecord

// At this point i want to save my Record. How can i do it
def rec = new Record(person: personInstance, schedule: scheduleInstance, name: nameOfTheRecord)
```